# Sending SOAP request using PHP with complex type

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have to create a soap request to match this input xml

```
<api:objects> 
<api:nextObject xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance "xsi:type="api:Lead"> 
<api:Custom> 
<api:DisbursedAmount_L>25000</api:DisbursedAmount_L> 
<api:HoldingNo_L>GL010022016</api:HoldingNo_L>
<api:TransactionalStatus_L>Success</api:TransactionalStatus_L>
<api:DateofPurchase_L>02/10/2016</api:DateofPurchase_L> 
</api:Custom> 
<api:LeadKey>2279</api:LeadKey> 
<api:StatusCodeKey>100010</api:StatusCodeKey>
</api:nextObject> 
</api:objects>
```

How do I create tags with api:tagname? Also how to add xmlns:xsi and xsi:type to the tags. Please help! I am very new to soap and I am stuck with this complex structure and always I get an error object reference not set to an object.

My Code:

```
 class Custom{
public $DisbursedAmount_L;
public $HoldingNo_L;
public $TransactionalStatus_L;
public $DateofPurchase_L;       

    function __construct($DisbursedAmount_L,$HoldingNo_L,$TransactionalStatus_L,$DateofPurchase_L) {
            $this->DisbursedAmount_L = $DisbursedAmount_L;
            $this->HoldingNo_L = $HoldingNo_L;
            $this->TransactionalStatus_L = $TransactionalStatus_L;
            $this->DateofPurchase_L = $DateofPurchase_L;
        }


    }


    class nextObject
    {
    public $LeadKey;
    public $StatusCodeKey;

    function __construct(Custom $custom,$leadkey,$statuskey) {

        $this->Custom=$custom;      
        $this->LeadKey = $leadkey;
        $this->StatusCodeKey = $statuskey;  

    }

}
$custom_obj=new Custom(1,2,3,4);
$custom_obj1=new Custom(5,6,7,8);

$sdetail=array(); 
array_push($sdetail, new nextObject($custom_obj,'sgd','sgfd'));
array_push($sdetail, new nextObject($custom_obj1,'abc','def'));

 $data = $wsclient->Save(array("userContext" => $obj_usrdisp, "objects"=>$sdetail, "returnObjectOnSave" => false));
                 echo htmlentities($wsclient->__getLastRequest());
```

o/p of last reques

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.crmnext.com/api/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Save><ns1:userContext><ns1:IsSuccess>true</ns1:IsSuccess><ns1:ExpiresOn>2016-06-29T12:31:20.435685+05:30</ns1:ExpiresOn><ns1:IsUTC>false</ns1:IsUTC></ns1:userContext><ns1:objects><ns1:CRMnextObject/><ns1:CRMnextObject/></ns1:objects><ns1:returnObjectOnSave>false</ns1:returnObjectOnSave></ns1:Save></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: do you have wsdl file for the API ? if so then try with wsdl.

Comment: @Amila I have a URL which points to wsdl..I did not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: use SoapClient() with wsdl. http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: @Amila Please see my updated code to see what I have done till now

Comment: What returning for __getLastRequest() ? first better to try with SoapUI to check is it working on not.

Comment: @Amila i have updated the last request code

Comment: check your request xml . its not correctly generated for your request

Comment: @Philomath Any update on this. Have you figured out the issue? I'm also having same issue?